# Syntax for merging dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am curious why this works

```
m1, m2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a1': 11, 'b': 2}
{**m1, **m2}
```

while this does not:

```
{**m for m in (m1, m2)}
```

Wouldn't it make sense for dict comprehension to 'understand' the new syntax?

*Edit (hopefully, temporary): in response to 'possible duplicate' flag. I am aware of that other question. I hope it is clear that I am not asking how to merge dictionaries.*

Comment: Disallowing unpacking is standard among all comprehensions as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about the justification in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ yourself.

From what I gather, the concerns were about clarity and confusion with function call argument expressions. As it is with these matters of taste the answer might not be as satisfying as one wishes for.

Comment: They don't give the justification, but it is good to see they considered it: "This PEP does not include unpacking operators inside list, set and dictionary comprehensions although this has not been ruled out for future proposals."

Comment: Oh. Good for you reading it even bette than me ;8